# why does this mysql query still run without the proper ON condition

Tags: mysql

When debugging someone code I found that one of the queries was causing the temp table of mysql to run out of memory. I found that the query was executing even though the 'ON' condition did not have an equals to match the fields. I was wondering...

What this would actually do as this seemed to cause a horrendous performance lag?

(I ran the explain command which didn't seem to help)

As a very rudimentary example it would look something like this query:

```
"SELECT testfield
FROM foo f
LEFT JOIN bar b ON b.testid 
WHERE testid = 40365";
```

Comment: There is a manual for this kind of questions: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because you're joining on condition TRUE, which means this operation is a bit like a cartesian product.

I guess your tables are big enough to cause this memory problem.